# Ionic ngIf animation

Tags: animation, ionic3, angular5, ng-animate

I am working on a ionic application and added ngAnimations but this isn't running smooth because I set this animation on the state of the div and it appears when `this.clicked = true;`

Here is a link to a gif [LINK](https://media.giphy.com/media/5bgNxNs6pgBZNZQzYh/giphy.gif) to show you how it animates. It first shows below the current div and than when it disappears it is getting animated.

Here is the code of how I am doing it:

```
animations: [
    trigger('itemState', [
        state('void', style({
            transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
        })),
        transition('* => void', animate('500ms ease-out')),
        transition('void => *', animate('0.5s 500ms ease-out'))
    ])
]
```

The html:

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
  <div @itemState *ngIf="!clicked">
     <div class="availability-btn-wrapper" *ngFor="let availableDaysBtn of availableDays" (click)="getDay(availableDaysBtn)">
        <button ion-button round outline>{{ availableDaysBtn }}</button>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div @itemState *ngIf="clicked">
       <div class="availability-btn-wrapper" *ngFor="let availableTimeBtn of availableTimes" (click)="getTime(availableTimeBtn)">
          <button ion-button round outline>{{ availableTimeBtn }}</button>
       </div>
  </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

How can I smoothly show the second horizontal button row?